# Facebook android SDK 3.0 - NullPointerException at .getInnerJSONObject()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.0 (final release) for Android. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `.getInnerJSONObject()` at times (not always) when i try to post a new status on logged in user's feed. Following is the code i'm using inside `new Request.Callback(){}`:

```
public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                           .getGraphObject()
                                           .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("", "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(SessionLoginSampleActivity.this, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SessionLoginSampleActivity.this, "Post successful " + postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: you should probably check for an error before trying to get the inner JSON object

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The error most likely comes become the var response was not set properly; I suggest you debug and post here if you find more, do not get discouraged if this question gets negative votes

Comment: it should be a rule: if you post a problem involving exception, *always* remember to post according stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for the rule related info. I sure would. But in this, case all the helpful text in the errorstack was "nullpointerexception" .... other lines in the trace just pointed to the line of code.... which i already mentioned in the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was an error in the request, response.getGraphObject() returns null.

Code using Response should always check that response.getError() returns null before accessing getGraphObject().

There are three constructors for Response: one that takes a GraphObject, one that takes a GraphObjectList, and one that takes a FacebookRequestError, and all fields are final.  So only one of these can ever be non-null on any Response object.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this and just to share what i have had, maybe the supplied url or link is invalid that is why it gives nullpointerexception.
Hope this will help others that can experience this situation.